# How to throttle requestFrameAnimation on a range input?

Tags: javascript, range, debouncing

I have a simple range input and I would like to return the value, every few seconds.

I created two callback functions `func` and `step`. I would like to create another callback function that gets called every `x` seconds from inside `rangeListener`

Any ideas?

edit: edited per comments.

```js
class Test{
    rangeListener(range, func, step) {
        range.addEventListener("change", function () {
            func(range.value);
        });

        let listener = function () {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                step(range.value);
            });
        };

        range.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
            listener();
            range.addEventListener("mousemove", listener);
        });

        range.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
            range.removeEventListener("mousemove", listener);
        });

        range.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    }
}

let test = new Test();

test.rangeListener(document.querySelector(".range"), (value) => {

  document.querySelector(".value").innerHTML = value;

}, (step)=> {

  document.querySelector(".step").innerHTML = step;

});
```

```html
<input type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">

<div class="value">0</div>
<div class="step">0</div>
```

Comment: A little confused. "I would like to create another one that gets called every x seconds." Technically this has nothing to do with debouncing a function.

Comment: What's wrong with `setTimeout`?

Comment: Well, when I drag the slider, I get every step value. I want to get it every few seconds. I think that's `debouncing `. but i could be wrong

Comment: Nothing wrong with `setTimeout`. I'm ok with a solution using it. I just know there is a way to not use that  with `requestAnimationFrame `

Comment: sounds like you want `throttle` not `debounce` Lodash has both of them  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#throttle

Comment: @Xotic750 The Lodash method you link to requires to be given a number of milliseconds, so it can set a timeout (so, not really what OP is asking for). It's easy to set a flag for that purpose: https://jsfiddle.net/4xLymm5e/ That being said, for doing it _every x seconds_, he'll need a timer.

Comment: `Nothing wrong with setTimeout` :) The main thing was to clarify what the OP actually wants as it is a little unclear.

Comment: @blex can u add a timer to your example?

Comment: @Patrioticcow Does that suit your needs? https://jsfiddle.net/1fg6bj85/

Comment: So it's a `setTimeout` solution? :)

Comment: @Xotic750 Haha, for the _interval_ part, yes, there's no other simple way. For the throttle part where he is using `requestAnimationFrame`, though, he can keep using it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The throttle part**

An easy way to throttle function calls is to use a flag (boolean variable). It works like this:

- Set the flag to `false`
- In your throttled function, don't do anything if the flag is set to `true`
- Otherwise, set it to `true` and execute your function
- When it's done, reset the flag to `false`, to allow later calls

**The interval part**

If you want to execute a function every `X` seconds, your best choice is to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. However, there are multiple ways to do it, and depending on your usage, you might prefer using one or the other. For example, with this code:

```
setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
```

Your function will wait 5 seconds before being executed.

If you want the first execution to happen immediatly, you can do this (using an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) here):

```
(function myInterval(){
    myFunc();
    setTimeout(myInterval, 5000);
})();
```

**The result, with your code**

I adapted your code below to incorporate these changes:

```js
class Test {
  rangeListener(range, options) {
    /*
     * This flag will be set to true when we are waiting
     * for the next AnimationFrame, and back to false
     */
    let throttling = false;
    let timer;

    /*
     * Functions
     */
    const changeListener = () => {
      if (!options.onChange) return;
      options.onChange(range.value);
    };

    const stepListener = () => {
      if (!options.onStep || throttling) return;
      throttling = true;

      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        options.onStep(range.value);
        throttling = false;
      });
    };

    const intervalFunc = (isInitialization = false) => {
      if (!options.onInterval) return;
      options.onInterval(range.value);
      if (!isInitialization) {
        timer = setTimeout(intervalFunc, options.delay || 500);
      }
    };

    /*
     * Event listeners
     */
    range.addEventListener("change", changeListener);

    range.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      intervalFunc();
      stepListener();
      range.addEventListener("mousemove", stepListener);
    });

    range.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      // Execute it once more to get the last value
      intervalFunc();
      clearTimeout(timer);
      range.removeEventListener("mousemove", stepListener);
    });

    range.addEventListener("keydown", stepListener);

    /*
     * Values initialization
     */
    changeListener();
    stepListener();
    intervalFunc(true);
  }
}

let test = new Test();

const setHTML = (selector, value) => {
  document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = value;
};

test.rangeListener(document.querySelector(".range"), {
  onChange: (value) => setHTML(".value", value),
  onStep: (value) => setHTML(".step", value),
  onInterval: (value) => setHTML(".delayed", value),
  delay: 300
});
```

```html
<input type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">

<div>onChange: <span class="value">0</span></div>
<div>onStep: <span class="step">0</span></div>
<div>onInterval: <span class="delayed">0</span></div>
```

Comment: one thing I noticed is that `intervalFunc();` needs to be inside `range.addEventListener("mousedown"..` so the timer starts when I start dragging the slider. and then `clearTimeout(timeout);` inside the `changeListener` so that the timer stops when I stop dragging

Comment: @Patrioticcow I misunderstood your question, then. I thought you wanted to execute it every `x` seconds, independently from the fact that it's being dragged or not. I'll adapt it.

Comment: I edited the code, it might be closer to what you actually want. Tell me otherwise